# Show that if $\operatorname{tr}(A+B) > \operatorname{tr}(A)$ then $\operatorname{tr}((A+B)^k)\geq \operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ for any $k\geq 1$

Tags: matrices, summation

This may be a stupid question, but I am completely stuck, I don't even know where to start. I have to show that if $\operatorname{tr}(A+B) > \operatorname{tr}(A)$ then $\operatorname{tr}((A+B)^k)\geq \operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ for any $k\geq 1$, where $A$ and $B$ are square symmetric matrices with real entries.

Any help is welcome, thank you very much in advance

In response to Calvin's answer, I checked the condition again, in fact, the first inequality is a strict one. Furthermore, $A$ is positive semi-definite. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Have you tried a proof by induction on $k$? Also, the symmetry is important here.

Comment: Unfortunately, as there is no simple formula for the trace of a product of matrices, I don't see how to use induction here.

Comment: I would suggest that you repost the question, along with all the conditions in the question. The positive semi-definite aspect is quite important. You also need it for both $A$ and $B$ (my A is positive, so still a valid counter example to your current statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem statement should require that both $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinate. Otherwise, the following is a counterexample to the problem as initially stated.

---

The statement is not true. Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0  \\ \end{pmatrix}$.

The given condition is true since both traces are 2. However, the inequality for $k=2$ gives  $2 \geq 4$.

You might want the entries to be positive (non-negative).

---

If the first inequality was strict, use $B = \begin{pmatrix} \varepsilon & -1 \\ -1 & \varepsilon \end{pmatrix}$, where $\varepsilon$ is a small positive value (like $0.01$). It increases the trace of $A+B$ , and only perturbs the trace of $(A+B)^2$ by a small amount, so the condition we want to prove is still false.