# If $\operatorname{tr}(A+B)>\operatorname{tr}(A)$, does it hold that $\operatorname{tr}((A+B)^k)>\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ for all $k\geq 1$

Tags: matrices, summation

I wonder whether the following holds and if so how it could be proved:

Let $A, B$ be (non-commuting) positive semi-definite matrices,

If $\operatorname{tr}(A+B)>\operatorname{tr}(A)$, does it hold that $\operatorname{tr}((A+B)^k)>\operatorname{tr}(A^k)$ for all $k\geq 1$.

Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Note that by linearity of trace, $tr(A+B) \gt tr(A)$ amounts to $tr(B) \gt 0$.

Comment: May we assume $A,B$ *symmetric* PSD matrices?

Comment: They both are symmetric and psd, yes

Comment: I am sure this has been asked recently... I am not sure if that has been answered... I could not find a link for that though..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: This version restricts the conditions to PSD matrics, see the first Related link at right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show that if $tr(A+B) > tr(A)$ then $tr((A+B)^k)\geq tr(A^k)$ for any $k\geq 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680680/show-that-if-trab-tra-then-trabk-geq-trak-for-any-k-geq-1)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, the conditions differ

Comment: There also you have mentioned that they are positive semi definite right? Are you sure you understood the answer there?

Comment: Please do read carefully, here A and B are psd unlike in the other question

Comment: Oh yeah... I have read the comments below the question... Calvin suggested you to repost the question with extra condition.. That is alright then...

Answer (score 1):

Very partial answer:

It is true for k=2:

$tr((A+B)^2)=tr(A^2+AB+BA+B^2)=tr(A^2)+tr(AB)+tr(BA)+tr(B^2)=tr(A^2)+2tr(AB)+tr(B^2)$

by linearity of trace and by the fact that $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$. Furthermore, as B is psd, $tr(B^2)\geq 0$, and $tr(AB)\geq 0$ (see A.U. Kennington, Power concavity and boundary value problems, Indiana University Mathematics Journal Vol.34, No. 3, 1985, p. 687-704, Appendix). Thus $tr((A+B)^2)\geq tr(A^2)$

Comment: We can get the strict inequality version as in the Question.  If $tr(A+B) \gt tr(A)$, then (and only then) $tr(B) \gt 0$.  Since $B$ is symmetric, pos. semi-def., then $tr(B^k) \gt 0$ for all natural numbers $k$, and this gives with the above reasoning $tr((A+B)^2) \gt \;tr(A^2)$.

Comment: This type of argument can be successfully carried out up to $k=5$ (as done here for $k=2$).  At $k=6$ we encounter terms like $AABABB$ which we cannot show have nonnegative trace with the same approach as (for example) we can for $AB$, $ABA$, etc.